# How to install/update/upgrade SSL certificate in Tomcat?

Tags: apache, https, security-certificate, linux, tomcat

I am about to install/update/upgrade a SSL certificate in one of the servers which has the following configuration

```
Sever information: Sever version: Apache Tomcat/6.0.35 OS version: Linux 2.6.18-371.6.1.el5 Architecture: amd64 JVM 
version: 1.6.0_30-b30 JVM 
Vendor: Sun Microsystems Inc. 
Tomcat location: /user/local/apache-tomcate-6.0.35
```

Generate new SSL certificate request:

1. I created a folder name keystore (`/user/local/apache-tomcate-6.0.35/keystore`)

   To create a key : 
   sudo keytool -storepass keypassword -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -keystore mydomain.keystore -genkey   -alias mydomain

To create SSL certificate request:

```
sudo keytool -storepass keypassword -keystore mydomain.keystore -certreq -keyalg RSA -file mydomain.csr -alias mydomain.com
```

After successful executing both the commands I got two files keystore folder - mydomain.keystore - mydomain.csr

The following files are attached into email I received yesterday

`Cabundle.cert` (What is this? No mention of it in the Wiki)
Zip file

1. `mydomain.crt`
2. `root_certificate.crt`
3. `Trend_Micro_CA.crt`
4. `Affirmtrust_Networking.crt`

Installing the certificate:

As per information from other source I downloaded two other files into keystore folder

http://secure.globalsign.net/cacert/ct_root.der
http://secure.globalsign.net/cacert/sureserverEDU.pem

Import the root certificate ‘ct_root.der’ :

```
[root@ mydomain keystore]#sudo keytool -keystore mydomain.keystore -storepass keypassword -importcert -file ct_root.der -trustcacerts -alias globalsignroot
```

Outcome: Certificate already exists in system-wide CA keystore under alias <3getcybertrustsolutionsincgtecybertrustglobal root> Do you still want to add it to your own keystore? [no]: yes Certificate was added to keystore

Import the sure server education certificate ‘sureserverDDU.pem’:

```
[root@ mydomain keystore]# sudo keytool -keystore mydomain.keystore –storepass keypassword -importcert -file sureserverEDU.pem -trustcacerts -alias sureserveredu
```

Outcome: Certificate was added to keystore

Import the certificate from email: As per wiki I need to import certificate.pem file
 {{{`sudo keytool -keystore mydomain.keystore -storepass keypassword -alias mydomain -import -file mydomain.pem`}}}.

I don’t have any .pem file in the email I have received and if I run 
`[root@ mydomain keystore]# sudo keytool -keystore mydomain.keystore -storepass keypassword -alias mydomain -import -file mydomain.crt`. 
I get an error,
Keytool error: java.lang.Exceptoin: Failed to establish chain from reply

Problem:

This is where I am stuck and don’t know what to do, I assume I have to create a chain.pem with all the received certificates inside it. If this is the case in which order I should copy and paste the certificates?

To be honest I don’t want to try anything which I am not sure about it because it is a live server.

I will really appreciate if someone could help me/providing instruction on how to proceed beyond step #5 to successfully install the certificate. I am also confused what is `cabundle.crt` that comes with the email.

Comment: You can [convert your .crt to a .pem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4691699/how-to-convert-crt-to-pem): `openssl x509 -in mycert.crt -out mycert.pem -outform PEM`

Comment: @StephenOstermiller as per my ssl provider crt is in a pem format, 

"No conversion is necessary; the CRT is in PEM format. (Note that the cert in the body of the email from Trend Micro is PKCS7, but the one in the zipfile is PEM)."